# Simple regex help using C# (Regex pattern included)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I have some website source stream I am trying to parse. My current Regex is this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex (
@"<a\b             # Begin start tag
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to id attribute
    id\s*=\s*['""]?thread_title_([^>\s'""]+)['""]?  # $1: id
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to href attribute
    href\s*=\s*['""]?([^>\s'""]+)['""]?             # $2: href
    [^>]*              # Consume up to end of open tag
    >                  # End start tag
    (.*?)                                           # $3: name
    </a\s*>            # Closing tag",
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace );
```

But it doesn't match the links anymore. I included a sample string [here](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/00II).

Basically I am trying to match these:

```
<a href="http://visitingspain.com/forum/f89/how-to-get-a-travel-visa-3046631/" id="thread_title_3046631">How to Get a Travel Visa</a>

"http://visitingspain.com/forum/f89/how-to-get-a-travel-visa-3046631/" is the **Link**
304663` is the **TopicId**
"How to Get a Travel Visa" is the **Title**
```

In the sample I posted, there are at least 3, I didn't count the other ones.

Also I use [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/) (online and free) to see my matching interactively before adding it to code.

Comment: @Joan Venge For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Thanks pst, haven't seen that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, here how it's done with the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is a robust HTML parser for .Net (also available through [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), so installing it takes about 20 seconds).

Loading the document, parsing it, and finding the 3 links is as simple as:

```
string linkIdPrefix = "thread_title_";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/upixof");
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                              .Where(link => link.Id.StartsWith(linkIdPrefix));
```

That's it, really. Now you can easily get the data:

```
foreach (var link in threadLinks)
{
    string href = link.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
    string id = link.Id.Substring(linkIdPrefix.Length); // remove "thread_title_"
    string text = link.InnerHtml; // or link.InnerText
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", id, href);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple, the markup changed, and now the `href` attribute appears before the `id`:

```
<a\b             # Begin start tag
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to href attribute
    href\s*=\s*['""]?([^>\s'""]+)['""]?             # $1: href
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to id attribute
    id\s*=\s*['""]?thread_title_([^>\s'""]+)['""]?  # $2: id
    [^>]*              # Consume up to end of open tag
    >                  # End start tag
    (.*?)                                           # $3: name
    </a\s*>            # Closing tag
```

Note that:

- This is mainly why this is a bad idea.
- The group numbers have changed. You can use named groups instead, while you're at it: `(?<ID>[^>\s'""]+)` instead of `([^>\s'""]+)`.
- The quotes are still escaped (this should be OK in character sets)

Example on [regex hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=2509fab5-243f-4fa3-aeb2-61658ae38f7b).

Comment: Thanks, in your example link, is it modified? When I open it, it says 0 matches.

Comment: @JoanVenge - That is strange... I'll let it be, it already failed me trice, but I think the idea is clear anyway `:)` Thanks!

Comment: Regex Hero truncates the target string when using the permalink feature if it's longer than 4,000 characters.  It occurs to me that I should probably raise the limit.  @Joan - If you copy and paste your original html, then Kobi's regular expression should work.

Comment: I raised the limit to 500,000 characters.  So this should work... http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=2509fab5-243f-4fa3-aeb2-61658ae38f7b

Comment: @Steve, thanks man, it really works. Btw thanks Kobi for providing 2 great examples. I don't know regex but I tried your Agile sample and it works even better, so switched to that.

Comment: @Joan and Kobi - You're welcome.  And you're absolutely right in using HTML Agility Pack in the scenario.  It's what I would do as well.  By the way, I'm working on a new tool called XML Hero which will help with things like this.

Comment: @Steve: Is your tool something like Regex Hero?

Comment: @Joan - Yes, the details are being worked out as it's still early.  But it'll be a tool to help with XML and HTML parsing via XPATH and the Html Agility Pack.  The last feature I implemented is code completion, which is working great.  I'll also implement benchmarking and .NET code generation.  I'll send an email out to all registered Regex Hero users when it's released.

Comment: @Steve: Awesome man, I didn't know you wrote Regex Hero, had to look at your profile. Certainly great tools for developers.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (well, [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491), but it's not for everyone). [Parsers](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) are meant for that type of thing.

Comment: Thanks but I need a quickfix, not a major change. Besides it's a personal tool no one uses anyway. Also I see many instances of similar practice in production code, so I think even most programmers don't follow these good practices.